# What is the most popular database choice for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, database, mariadb

this question sounds more like a poll because I'm just curious as to what database is the most commonly used for Magento2. I currently use MariaDB 10 from following an installation tutorial online, but I'm a bit wary because I've recently read the official documentation and it says that MariaDB may not be fully compatible with Magento2. What is the most widely used database for Magento2?

Comment: check this https://onilab.com/blog/magento-2-mysql-optimization-and-database-performance-tuning/

Comment: Awesome, thank you Devidas

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I found out it's either MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/180325)

Comment: I am the author of the question, and from asking professional freelancers most of them says MySQL is the popular choice. I know "most popular" is rather subjective but I'm answering my own question based on what I have discovered on my own research